# Is there a way to create a usable scrollbar for a native IOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have been looking around stackoverflow and google trying to find this answer, I can't seem to find anything saying yes or no on it.

I have an app that has roughly 90,000 cells in a single view and scrolling through with swipe gestures works but is abysmally slow as you would think.

Now, there is a search function implemented that rapidly speeds up searching but the client would also like to add a clickable scrollbar like you see in regular web browsers. This app is made on both IOS and Android, the Android version was able to implement a scrollbar, and while I don't think it is necessary to have one, what the client wants, the client gets (if of course it is possible).

Is there a way to implement a scrollbar that would fit on the edge of the screen that is useable to rapidly scroll through literally thousands of cells of content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use an UISlider and rotate it by 90 degrees:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.5);
scrollSlider.transform = transform;
```

Then use your own image for a more scrollbar like look (empty images as background and a different shaped thumb image) using this functions:

```
- setMaximumTrackImage:forState:
– setMinimumTrackImage:forState:
– setThumbImage:forState:
```

After that you can use the value property of the slider to adjust the scroll position.

edit: You should hide the real scrollbar in this case and update the slider's value when the view was scrolled by the user using

```
-scrollViewDidScroll:
```

To get the math a little bit easier, you could set the min value of the slider to 0, and the max value to scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.size.height.

slider.value can be used directly as scrollView.contentOffset that way.

Comment: I will definitely try this, but it seems really hacky. Is this really the best/only way of doing it?

Comment: There isn't a real touchable scrollbar included in the iOS framework.
You could implement your own view with an image you drag around as a scroller. But in the end you would just re-implement a new UISlider.
UISlider is just a class that interpolates steps between its min and max value. So there's not so much difference to a real scrollbar on other OSs

Comment: Alright cool, I will let the question be open till tomorrow then will mark your answer as correct if nothing else comes up. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.
I also added some more toughts about the implementation above.
Shouldn't be more than a few lines of code that way.